# New "File" in java

Tags: java, exception

***1.*** what does `new file` in `new File("scores.dat")` line mean? It will create a new file?

***2.*** When I run this piece of code, I get this as output:
"*java.io.FileNotFoundException: scores.dat (The system cannot find the file specified)*"
Does anybody know what the problem is?

***3.*** There is not any "`finally`" section in this code; putting "`finally`" is optional in `exceptions`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadAndPrintScores
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        try
        {
            Scanner s = new Scanner( new File("scores.dat") );
            while( s.hasNextInt() )
            {
                System.out.println( s.nextInt() );
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             System.out.println( e );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "It will create a new file?" No, it will create a new File object. "Does anybody know what the problem is?" Yes, the system cannot find the file specified, just as it says. And yes, `finally` is optional in `try`/`catch` blocks...

Comment: It seems you need to understand the basics of file I/O. You would definitely learn a lot and answer these question yourself if you do [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).

Comment: If you use Java 7+, please consider using java.nio.file instead.

Comment: @fge: yes, mine is java 8. I am studying some codes which I found in the net to learn java. This is one the codes which I think it is incomplete. because doesn't have **"scores.dat"** file. since, I am beginner, I don't know "java.nio.file" as well.

Comment: Also, look up try with resources for an easier alternative to a finally block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `new File()` is the constructor of `File` class. So a new instance of `File` will be created.
2. `scores.dat` must be a file that exists in the same directory of your code.
3. Yes `finally` is optional

Check the [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()) for more information about the `File` class.

Answer (score 1):

***1.*** `new File("scores.dat")` does **not** create the file. It will just create something like a handle to this file (whether it exists or not). You can use this `File` object to ask whether the file already exists, to create a new file if it does not exist yet, and so on. You can see a full documentation of the `File` class in the official [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

***2.*** Since you do not create the file by simply creating a `File` object for it, the file does not exist yet and so there is nothing to read from.

***3.*** The `finally` structure is optional. It is good practice to use it to make sure you close resources you do not need anymore, because `finally` blocks are always executed if their according `try` block was entered. Read more about the `finally` keyword [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html).